# Enabling/Disabling IntelliJ's fancy ≠ (not equal to) operator

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, code-formatting

I witnessed this in the [GOTO 2016 • Kotlin - Ready for Production](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0J_Jl7bKY8) conference by [Hadi Hariri](https://twitter.com/hhariri).

In some of his code, what would normally look like:

```java
if (x != y) { /* do some stuff */ }
```

Renders as:

```
if (x ≠ y) { /* do some stuff */ }
```

[image: Screen-shot from the live coding session]

The code uses the regular `!=` operator, and the IDEA takes care of the rest.

So, how can I enable/disable this?

Comment: Came here to find how to DISABLE it :) Thanks

Comment: Who came up with this... ‍♂️

Comment: @SergeyKolodyazhnyy I would speculate that this was a marketing move from JetBrains as they were releasing Kotlin around the same time, wanting it to look cool and modern by introducing this ligature ... :)) (I am still a big fan of JetBrains though !)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

> To enable ligatures, go to the Settings → Editor → Colors & Fonts →
>   Font, choose a font that supports ligatures, e.g. FiraCode, Hasklig,
>   Monoid or PragmataPro (the font has to be installed) and select the
>   Enable font ligatures option.

Source: [link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/06/intellij-idea-2016-2-eap-case-only-renames-in-git-ligatures-background-images-and-more/).

To preview some fonts, including several with ligatures: https://app.programmingfonts.org/

Comment: Now with 2018.3: `File > Settings > Editor > Font > Enable font ligatures`. Ensure you are using e.g. FireCode or download it here: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases

Comment: And if you want to _get rid_ of it in Reader Mode (seems to be enabled in 2020.3 EAP by default), `Editor -> Reader Mode -> Font Ligatures` is the checkbox is you want to uncheck.... :)

Comment: This doesn't disable ligatures in read-only files. Any help?

Comment: @kajacx: PerLundberg's comment on this answer answers that; it needs to be disabled in Reader Mode: `Editor -> Reader Mode -> Font Ligatures`

Comment: Worked for me with JetBrainsMono, thanks

Comment: Note that if you have a file open and @PerLundberg's solution doesn't work then you may need to close and reopen the file. That worked for me.

Comment: In Rider 2022.1.2 I can't disable ligatures. Even when the toggle is disabled in settings != is still replaced with ≠. Font is Jetbrains Mono.

Answer (score 21):

This is the "font ligatures" feature, which uses [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature) to combine the characters in fonts that support them.  This feature is disabled by default in the standard editor, and enabled by default in the [Reader mode](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/12/intellij-idea-2020-3/#user_experience) introduced in 2020.3.

This feature can be enabled & disabled for the current project in the [project settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-project-settings.html) window (`File | Settings…` in Windows and Linux or `IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences…` in macOS).

The settings are located in the settings window at:

- **Editor**: `Editor | Font` -> "Enable font ligatures" checkbox
- **Reader Mode**: `Editor | Reader Mode` -> "Font ligatures" checkbox

Comment: in mine, reader mode is off, font ligatures is off - still getting the funky characters

Answer (score 13):

*Goland 2020.3* (and maybe other versions too) seems to have a bug. Enabling and disabling `Goland` -> `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `Font` -> `Enable font ligatures` works well on normal files but doesn't take effect on files under the `vendor/` directory. These files need to be closed and reopened in the editor.

Comment: Same for PHPStorm :3

Answer (score 7):

I use Material Design Theme with Android Studio 4.0, navigate to:

> File->Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->Color Scheme Font

and check Enable Font Ligatures.Do the same for:

> File->Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->Console Font.

This is after choosing FiraCode as your font in inteliJ. Find it [here](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases/download/5.2/Fira_Code_v5.2.zip) and install it as a normal font.

Comment: Use this method if you have Material Design Theme installed!

Answer (score 4):

This is "font ligatures", which is a feature of certain fonts to display two characters into a single symbol (but the two characters are still there in the file). You can search the Preferences page for "ligatures" and check to enable. You'll also need to use a font that supports ligatures, such as Fira Code.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but in the 2023.3.4 version of IntelliJ I had to go into `Settings` then from the top-level search for `Ligatures`.  To find the correct place to update this setting, because I was using a custom Scheme which had this setting turned on.

Editorial comment, I dislike this feature I just want to see `x != y`. :)